# Docker Container sh: 1: node: Permission denied when running using PHP

Tags: php, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've got an application which is written in three technologies: PHP, Node.js and Python.

I created basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y

RUN apt-get install -y \
    tesseract-ocr \
    tesseract-ocr-all \
    unzip \
    curl

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

COPY . .

RUN php composer.phar update

ENV NODE_VERSION=18.17.1
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version

WORKDIR /var/www/html/screenshot

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

and `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - php-fpm

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
      args:
        user: root
        uid: 1000
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
```

which create docker image successfully and start containers, however PHP code (which triggers another Node script) is unable to start
`shell_exec('cd dist && node index.js');` <- this is how PHP executes command for Node start
After that I can see logs in the container:
`sh: 1: node: Permission denied`.

I'm pretty certain that I'm missing some configuration in docker compose or dockerfile, could you please suggest some relevant configurations that can be necessary?

Comment: Does your application contain a PHP component, and a Node server component?  You should normally run these in two separate containers; the second container could use an image built `FROM node` and you won't have to worry about these installation problems.

Comment: PHP component is connected with nginx web server. We trigger php execution by endpoint localhost:8080. Then PHP runs code and at some point it needs switch execution to Node.js. PHP code just runs `shell_exec('cd /dist && node index.js);` and waits until Node finishes processing.
The point is the whole workflow is connected between those three environments: PHP, Node, Python. Running Node in separate container probably would require significant restructure of Node and Python initialization in PHP code, but I can be wrong.

Comment: I can attempt to run it in separate containers, perhaps triggering it will work. Not sure how to execute code from one container in another which were built using the same docker compose

Comment: Make an HTTP request from one container to another, or use a message queue like RabbitMQ.

Comment: Got it, thanks! 
however there's no HTTP connection with Node or Python. They can be run using command line, what's from my point of view complicates things :(

Comment: Can you wrap your application in an Express or Flask server, respectively?